# Let $f:\mathbb{E} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$,where $\mathbb{E},\mathbb{F} $ are normed space,such that:

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

(I) $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y). $

(II) $f$ is bounded in $B(0,1)$.

Then $f \in L(E,F)$

My attempt:
I proved $f (q x) = q x$ for all $x \in E$ y $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Now I want to
prove that $f (r x) = r f (x)$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}, x \in E$. I know
it's enough asume $r \in (0, 1)$. Then exists $q_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such as
$q_n \rightarrow r$. Thus
$$\lim f (q_n x) = \lim q_n f (x) = r f (x) . $$
So if I prove that $f (q_n x) \rightarrow f (r x)$, I would have what I want.

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: You have not used II yet.

Comment: You want to take your rational sequence $x_n$ to converge to $x$. The factor $f(x)/x$  is a constant and should not depend on whether $x$ is rational or not.

Comment: @daruma You need to prove continuity for the convergence to be at all meaningful!

Comment: Yeah, I am not arguing with that, it's mentioned in your answer so there wasn't a point to repeat the same thing twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We prove that $f$ is continuous; then you have what you need to finish your limiting arugment. We imitate the standard proof that bounded linear functions are continuous, except this time we only have additivity and $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity.

By the additivity, we can translate and so $f$ is continuous at 0 if and only if its continuous everywhere.

Now, we show continuity at 0. Fix $\epsilon > 0.$ Since $f$ is bounded on $B(0,1),$ say that if $|x| < 1$ then $|fx| < B$ for some finite constant $B.$

Pick $q$ rational so that $0 < q < \epsilon/B.$ If $|x| < q,$ then we claim $|fx| < \epsilon.$ Since $f(0) = 0$ by additivity, this is enough to prove continuity at 0.

And indeed, if $|x| < q$ then $|x/q| < 1.$ And so $|f(x/q)| < B.$ But then $|f(x)/q| = |f(x/q)| < B$ since you can prove $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity. Now $|f(x)| < qB$ since $q > 0.$ But $q < \epsilon/B,$ and so this means $|fx| < \epsilon.$ We have continuity! Now your limit argument goes through.